# Count how many times a particular value appears with respect to value in another column

Tags: spotfire

I want to count how many times a particular value appears with respect to value in another column. ( Apologies, as i am struggling to put it in words properly. Maybe that's why I couldn't google it)

I am using spotfire and actual data set is quite big.

As per my dummy data - i want 5 more columns - a,b,c,d,e which will give me counts like table - 'what I want'
[image]

Please if someone can help.

Thanks,
AP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you're looking for is called a **Pivot Table**. it doesn't look quite like what you've got in your example, and because you haven't provided a lot of information about what you're trying to do in the end, I'm working under the assumption it's just a quick example you put together? if that's not the case, [please clarify your question with your end goal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and I'll update my answer.

to create a Pivot Table in Spotfire:

1. click the **Insert** menu at the top of the screen
2. choose **Transformation...**
3. in the *Insert Transformation* dialog that appears, choose your data table from the top dropdown, and choose **Pivot** from the bottom one, then click **Add...**
4. configure the pivot like I've done in the screenshot below
5. click **OK** and confirm the *Insert Transformation* dialog

[image]

Comment: Thanks @niko.... I know about Pivot function in Spotfire but I couldn't figure out that It is what i need.  It solved my problem Cheers.